# mysql count duplicates

Tags: mysql

How can I count duplicated rows within the `select` statement?

Here is my table:

| name | food |
| --- | --- |
| A | Apple |
| B | Banana |
| A | Banana |
| C | Apple |

The result should be like this:

| name | food | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | apple | (2) |
| B | Banana | (1) |
| A | Bananaa | (2) |
| C | Apple | (1) |

I need a third column in the result set in which the value will be `count(Name)`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 52):

```
SELECT name, food, COUNT(food) AS cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY name, food
HAVING (cnt > 1)
```

If you want the count of everything, not just the tuples with duplicates, then eliminate the HAVING line, as that'll filter out anything that doesn't have duplicates.

Answer (score 38):

It's unclear exactly what you want to do, so here's two possibilities.

If you want to determine how many times the same `name` and `food` combination occurs, you can use `GROUP BY` to group like records and `COUNT` to determine how many there are in the group:

```
SELECT name, food, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY name, food
```

Alternately, if you want to retrieve how many times only the name duplicates, you'll need a subquery:

```
SELECT name, food,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM your_table_name
    WHERE name = table_alias.name
  ) AS count
FROM your_table_name AS table_alias
```

The first query will return only one row per `name`/`food` group, along with the count of how many records appear in the group. The second query will return all rows, with a count of how many rows have the same name in each row.

Comment: I have bean waiting my time yesterday counting the data manually, when there is some thing like this. Thanks a lot.