# notifications feature reducing similar activity by summing count

Tags: php, mysql

For notifications table in mysql database, I have stored activity_type, parent_ID, parent_type and timestamp.

I know how to listing it 1 row by 1 row Order by time, however I want do do it like how facebook do, such as

> 29 July
>
> > you have 10 notification of activity_type=1, from parent_ID=1,parent_type=1
> >
> > you have 1 notification of activity_type=1, from parent_ID=2,parent_type=1
>
> 28 July
>
> > you have 30 notification of activity_type=2, from parent_ID=1,parent_type=2

Comment: give some time on group by statement of sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link [mysql count duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935078/mysql-count-duplicates)
solved the problem!

```
SELECT name, food, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY name, food
```

just do some changes to the variable name