# count total numbers of same item exist in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

assume I have a table that contain a column named post_id and it has the result like

```
1
1
1
2
2
3
1
1
```

I want to loop through all the records and count how many times they exist. What I could thought of is

by while loop

if(result[] = 1){$1++}, but the problem is the value of record is not fixed, it can be 9999..

I'd tried

```
while ($something= $item->fetch_array()) {
  while($test[] = $something['post_id'] > 0){
//logic here
 }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql count duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935078/mysql-count-duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select post_id, count(*)
from table
group by post_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can do in SQL. I believe it would be the following:

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY post_id;
```

This will return, for each post_id in the table, that post_id and the count of rows with that post_id.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You will get two columns from that query, the first is the post_id, the second is the count of rows with that ID. You can use fetch_array and then access $arr[0] or $arr[1].

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this.
Assume:

Table one

```
**Table one** 
Column1
1
1 
1 
2 
2 
3
1 
1
```

You can use this query to count it.

```
  SELECT one.column1, COUNT(two.column1) FROM one as one, one as two;
```