# Count and sum up all duplicate records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have table with, following structure.

```
id   name  
1    john
2    ana
3    john
4    ana
5    peter
6    ana
7    Abrar
8    Raju
```

Duplicate entries in the table are as follows

```
john(2)  duplicate
ana(3)  duplicate
```

The names which are duplicates are john and ana.

My question is how would I count the records in total which are duplicate here it is '5' records

Note : I also followed the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935078/mysql-count-duplicates) in community but it explains how we can add the number of duplicates exists for that particular name in the table and adds up the third column in table representing the duplicates records with same name but in my case I wanted to know the number of all duplicates exist in the table (here the result of the query is just number "5") irrespective of the names.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528644/count-duplicates-records-in-mysql-table and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql

Comment: @DeadManAlive Good links, but the queries in all 3 accepted answers are not identical to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a count subquery on the query you already have in mind (or perhaps have already written):

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) AS total_duplicates
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: what would be the SUM(cnt) here ?

Comment: @MohammedAbrarAhmed My Mac Book Air auto correct sometimes changes words into things for no reason at all.  Check the working demo.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Do not u think we should show them that this is duplicate question ?

Comment: @Dhaval I can't find an exact duplicate.  If you can, paste it here and I will close the question.